# Search for string w/delimiter character

Tags: c#, regex, file-io, filestream

I created a little console program that will search text files and return all string lines that matches a variable entered by a user.  One issue I ran into is, say I want to look up "1234" which represents a location code, but there is also a phone number that has "555-1234" in the string line, I get that one back too.   I am thinking if I input the delimiter (ex: ",") with the variable (",1234,") then maybe I can ensure search is accurate.  Am I on the right track, or is there a better way?  This is where I am at so far:

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);  
    foreach (string s in file) 
    {
       using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(rPath))
       {  
           if (sFound = Regex.IsMatch(s, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", 
               Regex.Escape(searchVariable))))
           {
               sw.WriteLine(s);
           }  
       }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a CSV file?

Comment: For the most part they will be csv files, but sometimes I come across pipe or ^ delimited files, so maybe I would have the user input the delimiter in the beginning.

Comment: Use Linq to CSV and make your life easier. Just go to Nuget and search Linq to CSV.

Comment: @jcwrequests you should probably add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you are on the right track.

I'd suggest changing the regular expressions so that it uses a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match "searchVariable" that is not preceeded by "-", so "1234" in "555-1234" wouldn't be matched, but ",1234" (for instance) would.

You will only need to use ["Regex.Escape()"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) if you want to include special regular expression characters in your search, which from your question you don't want to do.

You could change the code to something like this (it's late so I haven't tested this!):

```
var lines= File.ReadAllLines(sPath);
var regex = new Regex(String.Format("(?<!-){0}\b", searchVariable));

if (lines.Any())
{
 using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText(rPath))
 {    
  foreach (var line in lines) 
  {
   if (regex.IsMatch(line))
   {
    streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
   }  
  }
 }
}
```

A great website for testing these (often tricky!) regular expressions is [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Comment: How do I incorporate the user inputted variable with the regex variable?

Comment: @user2836200 I've updated the regex so the user inputted variable is now included. I've also altered the regex so that "-" in "555-1234" would not match but ",1234," (for example) would.

Comment: EEK!  I was forgetting to add String.Format which is why adding the variable wouldn't work for me.  I appreciate the feedback, but even the updated Regex will import additional strings if it contains say ",32541234," in the string line.  I think if I can match only what is between the delimiter it will be accurate every time.

Comment: I just realized you can use the delimiter in the Regex(String.Format(",\b{0}\b,", searchVariable))...   This seems to have solved my issue, at least for CSV files.   Now I just need to make the same thing work for PIPE & ^ delimited files.  Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @Mikem great news that you've got your problem fixed. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to CSV and make your life easier. Just go to Nuget and search Linq to CSV.

Comment: I'm new to writing code, so I looked up linq to CSV but I don't know enough to do anything with it.

Comment: Check out this link. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library